# restrict access to particular page for particular user

Tags: web-config, authorization, vb.net-2010

using vb.net . it contain one page named as trlist.aspx . i want to allow particular user(xxx,yyy) to access the page.Others are not allowed. i make some changes in web.config. but am not able to get the result.ie, access not denied for particular user. they are able to access it.

```
 web.config
```

---

```
 <location path="trlist.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="xxx,yyy"/> 

    <deny users="*"/>  
  </authorization>

</system.web>
```

Comment: How will the page load event know if the current user is user.... xxx or user yyy? unless you let it know before hand by one method or another?

Comment: @zaf Khan what should i do for this?

Comment: I think that you should use ASP.NET membership  and roles. There is a tutorial here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx